# push a route to change url without reload page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app.

my routing looks like this =>

```
<AppRoute path="/profile" exact={true} menuTitle="Profile" component={pages.Profile} />
<AppRoute path="/profile/post_feed" exact={true} menuTitle="Post Feed" component={pages.PostFeed} />
<AppRoute path="/profile/story_feed" exact={true} menuTitle="Story Feed" component={pages.StoryFeed} />
```

now in profile, there is some filter, so I would like to save them in the URL, to do so, I am using the following.

```
  const setQueryParams = (filterId: number | null) => {
    history.push(`${urlParams.pathname}?filterId=${filterId}`);
  };



  const handleFilterSelectionChange = (id: number) => {
    setQueryParams(id);
    //....
  };
```

but this trigger a COMPLETE refresh of the page... and all the query that are associated. I put the following effect in my `Profile` component ( the one called from the route)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('FY');
  }, []);
```

And this trigger at load, then for each filter, the page is fully refreshed. But I would like those thing to trigger once, and when the route don't change (only the query parameters) those effect don7t get retriggered. Is it possible ?

Comment: You could either use shouldComponentUpdate or push to the window history directly. I have an application similar to google maps where I update the URL frequently, and I use the window history directly for updates that I know I do not want re-renders.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use **replace** instead push

```
    const setQueryParams = (filterId: number | null) => {

        history.replace({ search: `?filterId=${filterId}` })// CHANGE HERE
    };



  const handleFilterSelectionChange = (id: number) => {
      setQueryParams(id);
    //....
  };
```

Comment: it does the same that push T.T

Comment: Sorry I forgot a relevant detail, check it now

Comment: it does still reload the page. there must be something in my code then. this solution works to you ?

Comment: it's really annoying to debug ahah, just removing `history.replace({ search: urlParams.search });` do the trick, but idk why it reload my route if I put it back.

Comment: Yes, this solution works for me. With ”put It back” you mean, goBack() to route?

Comment: If possible, provide more detail, like where ”history” came from